# Gdb empty string turns into gobbledygook when passed to function

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

Take a look at the gdb output below.  To recap: endString is an empty string, until it is passed as the argument to a constructor.

I'm stumped.  Would this maybe indicate stack corruption?

```
367     string endString = fTable[i][endTimeIndex];
(gdb) p endString 
$2 = ""
(gdb) n
369     TimeData endObj = TimeData(endString);
(gdb) step
TimeData::TimeData (this=0xbfb60550, fIsoTime=
    "\000F;\267\370\063(\267\f\361%\267\027\364%\267\023\000\000\000\230\000\000\000\000\300\067\267\004\357\067\267\300\063(\267\300\000\000\000\360\063(\267\364\037(\267\300\063(\267h\326\n\bx\b\266\277,i\031\267\300\063(\267l\361l\267\224I\r\b\314\307k\267\224I\r\b\324\333\r\b\270\b\266\277\265\207\061\267\220\000\000\000l\361l\267\250\b\266\277b\307k\267\344\b\266\277T\n\266\277h\326\n\bl\361l\267l\361l\267\324\333\r\b\330\b\266\277J\304k\267\340\b\266\277\344\b\266\277\330\b\266\277.\275k\267h\326\n\b$\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\230I\r\bl\361l\267\bI\r\b\370\b\266\277\200\276k\267\330\333\r\b\330\333\r\b\bI\r\bp\266k\267<\t\266\277l\361l\267\030\t\266\277\363\266k\267H\333\r\b\330\333\r\b\bI\r\bH\333\r\bl\361l\267l\361l\267X\t\266\277\327\255k\267H\333\r\bF1\031\267\bI\r\bwYh\267\300\063(\267\001\000\000\000\330\333\r\bH\333\r\bX\t\266\277]h\031\267h\t\266\277t\326\n\b\344\361h\267\000\000\000\000x\t\266\277MOh\267\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\021\001\000\000 \000\000\000\300"... <Address 0xbfb63000 out of bounds>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>, 
    __vtt_parm=<optimized out>) at TimeData.cpp:164
```

As requested:

```
(gdb) p endString 
$4 = ""
(gdb) p endString.size()
$5 = 0
```

Comment: I am not convinced that `endString` is really empty.  Why not print out `endString.size()`?  That `\000F` looks like a control character, and you can't "see" control characters when trying to print them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie see my update.  endString does truly look empty.

Comment: So the next question is *does your program work*?  Step into the `TimeData` function and print `fIsoTime.size()`.  Is it 0?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `fIsoTime.size()` is 135101376.  So what causes this?

Comment: `__vtt_parm=<optimized out>`  Are you debugging optimized code?

Comment: Nope, there is no -ON specified (we're using gcc).  We are using -march=native, but as far as I can tell that doesn't do any kind of optimization, at least not in same sense as -ON.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I recompiled without -march=native, and nothing changed.  Any other ideas?